# Tracking Google Analytics on ASP.NET Image

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-analytics

I need to track events for Google Analytics everytime someone downloads a document and have placed code in my asp:Image to do this but am not getting any realtime results. I've also tried placing the onclick on the asp:Hyperlink that surrounds the image, but it wasn't working that way either.

Here is the code from the ItemTemplate of the repeater that the images are located in.

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="FormHyperLink"  >
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="FormImage" OnClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Document']);" />
     </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

In Google Analytics, I have the goal set up as Category : Downloads, Action: Document. 
I can't specify one document that's getting downloaded since this is a repeater of images that when clicked on, download different documents.

Can someone help me try to figure out how to get these downloads tracked correctly? I can't really change the code because this site is getting used by hundreds of people internally and even more outside of our company.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here's the entire repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="FormRepeater">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <tr class="even">
            <td width="475"><%# Server.HtmlEncode(((Core.Domain.FormsLibrary.Form)Container.DataItem).Title) %></td>
            <td>
              <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="FileRepeater" OnItemDataBound="Files_ItemDataBound" DataSource='<%# ((Core.Domain.FormsLibrary.Form)Container.DataItem).Files %>'>
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="FormHyperLink"  >
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="FormImage" OnClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Document']);" />
                 </asp:HyperLink>
              </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="DescriptionPlaceHolder" Visible='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(((Core.Domain.FormsLibrary.Form)Container.DataItem).Description) %>'>
          <tr class="even">
            <td colspan="2"><%# Server.HtmlEncode(((Core.Domain.FormsLibrary.Form)Container.DataItem).Description) %></td>
          </tr>
          </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td><%# Server.HtmlEncode(((Core.Domain.FormsLibrary.Form)Container.DataItem).Title) %></td>
            <td>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="FileRepeater" OnItemDataBound="Files_ItemDataBound" DataSource='<%# ((Core.Domain.FormsLibrary.Form)Container.DataItem).Files %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="FormHyperLink" >
                      <asp:Image runat="server" ID="FormImage" OnClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Document']);" />
                   </asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="DescriptionPlaceHolder" Visible='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(((Core.Domain.FormsLibrary.Form)Container.DataItem).Description) %>'>
          <tr class="odd">
           <td colspan="2"><%# Server.HtmlEncode(((Core.Domain.FormsLibrary.Form)Container.DataItem).Description) %></td>
          </tr>
          </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Just checking: are you using classic GA (which uses the _gaq object) or Universal Analytics (which would use the ga object, and also different syntax for tracking events)?

Comment: unfortunately this site is using classic GA, not universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the onClick to the hyperlink but be sure to return true from the function (or create a new JS function that calls _gaq.push and then return true from that) so the click results in the link being followed.